# Determine container image digest via maven

Tags: docker, maven, maven-plugin

I'm currently using the [fabric8io - docker maven plugin](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin) to build container images.

I need to specify further container image labels - especially the opencontainer image labels documented [here](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/annotations.md#pre-defined-annotation-keys).

The label `org.opencontainers.image.base.digest` has a special meaning for me, because the image I build will be used as base image for further applications and I want to create a pedigree recursively for the complete container infrastructure.

Now the digest of the base container image is needed here. But I don't know how to query the digest in maven to specify it.

The plugin is currently configured as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <images>
            <image>
                <name>my/app</name>
                <build>
                    <dockerFile>${project.basedir}/Dockerfile</dockerFile>
                    <contextDir>${project.basedir}</contextDir>
                    <args>
                        <APP_NAME>app</APP_NAME>
                        <BASE_IMAGE_DIGEST>HOW TO DETERMINE?</BASE_IMAGE_DIGEST>
                        <BASE_IMAGE_NAME>docker.io/library/rockylinux:8.6</BASE_IMAGE_NAME>
                        <BUILD_DATE>${docker.app.image.created}</BUILD_DATE>
                        <GIT_TAG>${docker.app.image.version}</GIT_TAG>
                        <PROJECT_DOC>${docker.app.image.scm.url}#README</PROJECT_DOC>
                        <PROJECT_SCM>${docker.app.image.scm.url}.git</PROJECT_SCM>
                        <PROJECT_URL>${docker.app.image.scm.url}</PROJECT_URL>
                    </args>
                </build>
            </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>push</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>push</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The Dockerfile:

```yaml
ARG BASE_IMAGE_NAME

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE_NAME}

ARG APP_NAME
ARG BASE_IMAGE_DIGEST
ARG BASE_IMAGE_NAME
ARG BUILD_DATE
ARG GIT_TAG
ARG PROJECT_DOC
ARG PROJECT_SCM
ARG PROJECT_URL

# Open specifications from the Open Container Initative (OCI)
# https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/annotations.md#pre-defined-annotation-keys
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.base.name=${BASE_IMAGE_NAME} \
      org.opencontainers.image.base.ref=${BASE_IMAGE_DIGEST} \
      org.opencontainers.image.created=${BUILD_DATE} \
      org.opencontainers.image.description="My App" \
      org.opencontainers.image.documentation=${PROJECT_DOC} \
      org.opencontainers.image.source=${PROJECT_SCM} \
      org.opencontainers.image.title="My App Base image" \
      org.opencontainers.image.url=${PROJECT_URL} \
      org.opencontainers.image.version=${GIT_TAG}
```

Volker

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using `gmavenplus-plugin`. I've tested this with the aging Spotify Maven Plugin and it works as expected.

The script requires that you set the value `docker.base.image.name` via a property.

As I only work on GNU/Linux, I am unable to determine how this would be done on Windows or MacOs, but I have included profiles should someone work them out.

The plugin definition:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <!-- So long as this runs before the docker build, it's good -->
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                 <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
       <scripts>
           <!-- Run the script determined from OS profile -->
           <script>${base.image.digest.script}</script>
       </scripts>
   </configuration>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
           <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
           <version>4.0.15</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Then the profiles that will set the value of `base.image.digest.script`:

```
<profile>
    <id>unix</id>
    <activation>
        <os>
            <family>unix</family>
        </os>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <!-- Using CDATA just to be safe -->
        <base.image.digest.script><![CDATA[
            // Make sure we have the image
            "docker image pull ${docker.base.image.name}".execute()
            // Groovy doesn't handle quotes or pipes in shell commands very well, so we need this mess; assumption is a sha256 digest
            def process = "docker image inspect ${docker.base.image.name}".execute() | 'grep @sha256'.execute() | 'head -n1'.execute()
            // Split the digest to get the sha256 and remove the trailing quote
            def sub={ it.split("@")[1] }
            def digest = sub(process.in.text.trim()).take(71)
            println "Setting 'docker.base.image.digest' to '" + digest + "'"
            project.properties.setProperty('docker.base.image.digest', digest)
        ]]></base.image.digest.script>
    </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>windows</id>
    <activation>
        <os>
            <family>windows</family>
        </os>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <base.image.digest.script><![CDATA[
            println "!!!WARNING !!!"
            println "WARNING: Cannot determine base image digest on Windows"
            println "!!!WARNING !!!"
        ]]></base.image.digest.script>
    </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>mac</id>
    <activation>
        <os>
            <family>mac</family>
        </os>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <base.image.digest.script><![CDATA[
            println "!!!WARNING !!!"
            println "WARNING: Cannot determine base image digest on MacOS"
            println "!!!WARNING !!!"
        ]]></base.image.digest.script>
    </properties>
</profile>
```